# Code folding does not work in PydeV + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Just downloaded and installed Eclipse Classic, PyDev and the Java Runtime for Windows 64 bit.
All is fine, it seems to work ok - except code folding using the keyboard.
I have tried Ctrl + Numpad-Subtract, Numpad-Add and so on, I have assigned my own sahortcut keys - it simply won't work.

Note: Code folding works when using the mouse. But I program, I use the keyboard, so I need this to work using the keyboard. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is just figured out. The root cause is Eclipse by default uses the same key combinations for the standard code folding and PyDev's. So if the keys are changed to, such as Ctrl+9 for Collapse All, PyDev will collapse all code blocks without any issue.

The place to make the changes is Window>Preference>General>Keys>Python Collapse All